# How was the $3x+1$ problem checked up to $5 \times 2^{60}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, algorithms, computational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

The Wikipedia article for the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) states that:

> The conjecture has been checked by computer for all starting values up to $5 \times 2^{60} \approx 5.764 \times 10^{18}$.

It gives an inline citation to the URL http://www.ieeta.pt/~tos/3x+1.html which seems to have expired, and directs to a computational research institute called [IEETA](http://wiki.ieeta.pt/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) "Retrieved 27 November 2011".  Searching their site for `3x+1`, `Collatz` and `conjecture` left me empty handed.

> **Q**:  How was the $3x+1$ problem checked up to $5 \times 2^{60}$?

I'm particularly interested in if there are non-trivial algorithmic improvements over direct computation.  Or perhaps this was this simply a matter of *hit it with a big computer*?

Comment: I doubt you can hit it with a big enough computer to get to $2^{60}$, that's pretty intractable to do directly.  There have to be logical transforms to simplify it.

Comment: Someone will come in soon with more details, but as I understand it the short version is that you can sieve out a lot of residue classes by sort of running the problem 'in reverse'.  The phrase 'Collatz tree' might find you some useful information.

Comment: The question came up here about three years ago.  One of the references in the answers was at the IEETA site, which seems to have restructured its directory or dumped that material.  The other was this site:  http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/ (a link for technical details on computation is near the bottom in the section on computation records).  I also found some material here:  https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Collatz_conjecture.html (under 'Optimizations')

Answer (score 11):

It is enough to show that for each starting value $a_0>1$, there is some $k$ with $a_k<a_0$.

- We have $a_1<a_0$ if the step sequence starts with *down*, i.e. if $a_0\equiv 0\pmod 2$
- We have $a_3<a_0$ if the steps start *up,down,down* (because $\frac{3a_0+1}4<a_0$ for $a_0>1$); this rules out $a_0\equiv 1\pmod 4$
- Looking at *up,down,up,down,down,down*, we can exclude $a_0\equiv 3\pmod {16}$

Even after these simple remarks, we have already handled $81.25\,\%$ of all starting numbers.

More generally, a sequence of $u$ ups and $d$ downs implies that $a_{u+d}=\frac{3^u a_0+c}{2^d}$, where $c\in\mathbb N$ depends on the exact order of the ups and downs. Provided $3^u<2^d$, this eliminates the residue class $a_0\equiv 3^{-u}c\pmod{2^d}$ with possible small execptions (i.e. when $a_0\le \frac c{2^d-3^u}$).
The trick with pushing the bound for $a_0$ beyond $2^N$, is to continue investigating longer and longer sequences of *up* and *down*.

Comment: Can you please explain how you get 81.25% ?

Comment: The three bullit points cover $\frac 12$, $\frac14$, $\frac1{16}$ each (disjointly). $\frac12+\frac14+\frac1{16}=\frac{13}{16}=0.8125$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Is there supposed to be one more "down" for the case $a_0\equiv 3 \pmod {16}$? (Great answer by the way, +1)

Comment: @NotNotLogical If there were five downs, we'd talk about $\bmod 32$. Since $3^22^{-4}<1$, no fifth down is needed. Indeed, $3\stackrel{up}\mapsto 10\stackrel{down}\mapsto 5\stackrel{up}\mapsto 16\stackrel{down}\mapsto 8\stackrel{down}\mapsto 4\stackrel{down}\mapsto 2<3$ is fine,  as is $19\stackrel{up}\mapsto 58\stackrel{down}\mapsto 29\stackrel{up}\mapsto 88\stackrel{down}\mapsto 44\stackrel{down}\mapsto 22\stackrel{down}\mapsto 11<19$. There is of course a drawback in my answer as one might wrongly expect to need only a few tests to eliminate $99.999\%$, say. But progress is getting slower.

Answer (score 3):

The Collatz Conjecture says that starting with any integer $x \geq 1$, the Collatz sequence will eventually have an element equal to 1. It's quite easy to prove that it is equivalent to the following: For every $x \geq 2$, the Collatz sequence will eventually have an element less than x.

We change the rule so that $x$ is replaced with either $\frac{3x + 1}{2}$ or with $\frac{x}{2}$. We call replacing $x$ with $\frac{3x + 1}{2}$ an odd step, and $\frac{x}{2}$ an even step. If we have $o$ odd steps out of $n$ steps, then $x$ is replaced approximately with $\frac{3^o}{2^n}$. $x$ becomes smaller if $o \times \log_2 (3) < n$ or $o < 0.63093n$.

If you write $x$ as a binary integer, the last $n$ bits will tell you what the next $n$ steps of the sequence are. It also tells you whether after any of those $n$ steps the result was smaller than $x$. So you immediately exclude huge amounts of numbers from the calculation.

Then for those values of the last $n$ bits that pass this test, you look at the last $2n$ bits. Calculate what the last $n$ bits will be after $n$ steps, and check with precalculated data whether these 2n bits will lead to a smaller value within $2n$ steps.

Now you have hugely reduced the numbers that you need to examine. And you can perform $n$ steps of the calculation in one step. ($n$ will probably about 24 or so).